# Unable to catch InvalidCredentialsError with passport-activedirectory

Tags: javascript, passport.js

I am able to authenticate via LDAP, but I can't seem to figure out how to catch an error when a user enters an invalid username/password. I have failureRedirect and other stuff setup, but it doesn't get to that step in the authenticate function when an error does occur. I have tried putting in try catch functions with no luck either.

Here is the link to the authentication strategy being used: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-activedirectory

**front end** -I have tried changing the {{#if error}} to {{#if failWithError}} as well.

```
{{#if error}}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        Warning! {{error}}
    </div>
{{/if}}
```

**error message that is displayed to the user **

```
InvalidCredentialsError: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C5, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580
    at messageCallback (d:\........\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\client.js:1419:45)
    at Parser.onMessage (d:\........\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\client.js:1089:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Parser.write (d:\........\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\messages\parser.js:111:8)
    at Socket.onData (d:\........\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\client.js:1076:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
```

**block of code in ..\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\client.js line 1419**

```
if (expect.indexOf(msg.status) === -1) {
          return sendResult('error', errors.getError(msg));
        }
```

**auth.js**

```
module.exports = function(app,passport) {

    let opts = {
        failWithError: true,
        failureRedirect: '/',
        successRedirect: '/dashboard',
        failureFlash: true
    };
    app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('ActiveDirectory', opts), function(req, res) {
        res.json(req.user);
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) res.status(401).send('Not Authenticated');
    });
};
```

**passport.js**

```
module.exports = function(passport) {
    var ActiveDirectoryStrategy = require('passport-activedirectory');

    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) { done(null, user); });
    passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) { done(null, user); });

    passport.use(new ActiveDirectoryStrategy({
        integrated: false,
        passReqToCallback: true,
        ldap: {
            url: 'ldap://a.b.awesome:389',
            baseDN: 'DC=a,DC=b,DC=awesome',
            bindDN: 'CN=rando user,OU=users,DC=a,DC=b,DC=awesome',
            bindCredentials: 'ASecret',
            searchBase: 'OU=users,DC=a,DC=b,DC=awesome',
            searchFilter: '(sAMAccountName={{username}})',
            attributes: ['dn', 'displayName', 'givenName', 'sn', 'title', 'userPrincipalName', 'sAMAccountName', 'mail', 'description', 'memberOf'],
            logging: {
                name: 'ActiveDirectory',
                streams: [
                    { level: 'debug',
                        stream: process.stdout }
                ]
            }
        }
    }, function (req, profile, ad, done) {
        ad.isUserMemberOf(profile._json.dn, '123', function (err, isMember) {
            if (err)  return done(err);
            return done (null, profile)
        })
    }));

};
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to 'catch' the error and no longer display the error message to user.
However, express handlebars does not want to display my custom error message, I may be doing that wrong.

The answer for catching the error:
https://github.com/bhoriuchi/passport-activedirectory/issues/4

**auth.js**

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('ActiveDirectory', opts), function(req, res) {
        res.json(req.user);
    }, function(err, req, res, next) {
        let statusCode = /InvalidCredentialsError/.test(err.stack)
            ? res.redirect('/') && res.send( {error: 'Invalid Credentials!'} )
            : 500;
        return res.status(statusCode)
    });
```

**EDIT**

I also figured out how to send data to the front end to be displayed in a nice manner.

**new auth.js**

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('ActiveDirectory', opts), function(req, res) {
        res.json(req.user);
    }, function(err, req, res, next) {
        let statusCode = /InvalidCredentialsError/.test(err.stack)
            ? res.render('login', {failWithError: true, error: 'Invalid Username or Password!'})
            : res.status(500);
        return statusCode
    });
```

**front end .hbs**

```
{{#if failWithError}}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
       <strong>Error!</strong> {{error}}
    </div>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used your solution for a bit, but I think this works better IMO:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('ActiveDirectory', opts, (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err)
    }
    if (! user) {
      return res.redirect('/login')
    }
    req.login(user, (err) => {
      if(err) {
        return next(err)
      }
      return res.json(req.user)
    })
  }) (req, res, next)
})
```

Comment: Your first line of the answer says - "I used your solution for a bit".  Who is "your" here :). Also, it would be helpful if you could explain why your solution works better.